# Fetching image From Animating UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I'm using animation method of for implementing slide show in UIimageView as:

```
mainSlideShowImageView.animationImages=images;
mainSlideShowImageView.animationDuration = 75.00; 
mainSlideShowImageView.animationRepeatCount = 0; //infinite
[mainSlideShowImageView startAnimating];
```

Now, what I want is to know which image is currently on image view screen.

How can I do so?

If it is not possible please tell that too.

Edit: 'images' here is array of UIImage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no method which returns imageview's current image , however I have created a workaround for this....

```
array= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"3.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"4.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"5.jpg"],nil];
mainSlideShowImageView.animationImages= array;
mainSlideShowImageView.animationDuration=15.0;
i=0;
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self selector:@selector(increase) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[mainSlideShowImageView startAnimating];

-(void)increase
{
    i++;
    if (i>4) {
        i=0;
    }
}

-(void)getimage
{
    UIImage* im = [array objectAtIndex:i];
        // im is the current image of imageview

}
```

I have taken 5 images here and animation duration of 15 , that means image will change at every 3 seconds, so I have kept timer to fire at every 3 seconds ... and since array contains 5 images ... so if 'i' goes beyond 4 I have put it back to 0 in method increase