# Pulling image path from animation

Tags: iphone, ios, image, animation, path

I have a standard image animation for a simple banner. I'm trying to make it clickable so when the user clicks on the banner(a featured article list), it takes them to that article.

To achieve this in our Android version, we have a runnable that allows us to change both the image resource and the reference link at the same time.

I have the animation set up like this:

```
mBannerImageView.animationImages = newArray;
mBannerImageView.animationDuration = 10;
mBannerImageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
mBannerImageView.startAnimating;
```

Is there a way/how can I pull the resource name from the image view at the current time? My thought is to have the IBAction for it to pull the resource and direct you from there(matching the image name to something saved in our coredata). If there isn't a way, what would be the best approach for something of this nature?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try to attach [UIGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to your banner and handle touch event.

Comment: Ok, I can try that, but how does it know which picture is the current banner?

Comment: There are several SO posts that suggested the use of NSTimer. Try this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536915/fetching-image-from-animating-uiimageview).

Answer (score -1):

If you wish to set up image animation, so I have some html code which through you are easily generate image animation. The steps below show you how to create a image animation.

1. Create a simple animation and save the images as a series of JPG images.
2. Build an HTML page with the image displayed somewhere on the page using the  tag.
3. Save the file as logo1.htm. Within the  tag, include a  tag that looks like this:
   With the HTML file still open, change the  tag so that it displays the second frame of your animation, and change the  tag to open logo3.htm and save the file as logo2.htm.
   Repeat this process for all frames of the animation.