# how to take a screenshot of the UIImageView while animating images

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

i'm trying to capture the screen and it works perfectly when it has only one image in image view....but when i animate the UIImageView i'm getting a blank screenshot..

```
  CGRect rect = [self.view bounds];
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  [self.view.layer renderInContext:context];
  UIImage *capturedScreen = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
  UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(capturedScreen, nil, nil, nil);
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know whether my answer is right (or) wrong, but i tried it like this way...
[i got some code from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536915/fetching-image-from-animating-uiimageview/5537372#5537372)
thanks to [Iphone_bharat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/410389/iphone-bharat)

```
    -(void)change
     {
       if (i>=imags.count-1)
       i=0;
       else
       i++;
     }
    -(void)images      
       {
        NSArray *imagenames = @[@"1.png",@"b.png",@"c.png"];
        int j;
        NSMutableArray *images= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
           for (j=0; j<imagenames.count; j++)
               [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[imagenames objectAtIndex:j]]];
        self.imageview1.animationImages = images;
        self.imageview1.animationDuration =1;
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(change) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        [self.bground startAnimating];
        }
      -(IBAction)captureImage:(id)sender
      {
       self.imageview2.image = [images objectAtIndex:i];
       CGRect rect = [self.view bounds];
       UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
       CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
       [self.view.layer renderInContext:context];
       UIImage *capturedScreen = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
       UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
       UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(capturedScreen, nil, nil, nil);


      }
```